# How to count the number of times an element of a data frame appears in another data frame

Tags: r, stringr

I have 2 data frames. One is a list of vendors:

```
      vendor
1     apple
2     samsung
3     whirlpool
etc
.
.
.
```

and the other is an article about a particular vendor:

```
nbr     title     content
1       title 1   This is an article about apple
2       title 2   This is an article about whirlpool
3       title 3   This is an article about samsung
4       title 4   This is an article about apple and samsung
5       title 5   This is an article about none of them
etc
.
.
.
```

I've tried using many functions from the stringr package, but I don't want count just one term, I want to count the entire vendor list. I've tried using dplyr to group by and count but I couldn't get that to work the way I wanted it either.

In the end, I would like to have 2 output: the number of times each vendor is mentioned in all the articles.

```
apple       2
samsung     2
whirlpool   1
etc.
.
.
.
```

I would also like to see the number of times each vendor is mentioned in an article:

```
title     apple     samsung     whirlpool    etc...
title 1       1
title 2                                 1
title 3                   1
title 4       1           1
title 5
etc.
.
.
.
```

Comment: how many vendors do you have?

Comment: about 25, but the vendor list is changing too. The articles won't change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one solution:

```
mentions = stringr::str_extract_all(art$content, pattern = paste(v$vendor, collapse = "|"))
table(unlist(lapply(mentions, unique)))
# apple   samsung whirlpool 
#     2         2         1 

mentions = lapply(mentions, factor, levels = v$vendor)
t(sapply(mentions, table))
#         apple samsung whirlpool
# title 1     1       0         0
# title 2     0       0         1
# title 3     0       1         0
# title 4     1       1         0
# title 5     0       0         0
```

Using this data:

```
v = read.table(text = "      vendor
1     apple
2     samsung
3     whirlpool", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

art = read.table(text = "nbr     title     content
1       'title 1'   'This is an article about apple'
2       'title 2'   'This is an article about whirlpool'
3       'title 3'   'This is an article about samsung'
4       'title 4'   'This is an article about apple and samsung'
5       'title 5'   'This is an article about none of them'", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

If you have vendor names that might be mixed within other words, you might want to add word boundaries `"\\b"` before and after them before using them as regex patterns.

Comment: Great callout on adding boundaries using "\\b". Very prompt and intuiitve answer, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you call these two `vendor_df` and `df`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(content, sep=" ") %>% 
  inner_join(vendor_df, by = c("content" = "vendor")) %>% 
  count(content)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(content, sep=" ") %>% 
  inner_join(vendor_df, by = c("content" = "vendor")) %>% 
  mutate(value = 1) %>% 
  spread(key = content, value = value, fill = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sample data from @Gregor, for the first part, you can do:

```
colSums(sapply(v$vendor, function(x) grepl(x, art$content)))

apple   samsung whirlpool 
    2         2         1
```

For the second part:

```
mentions <- +(sapply(v$vendor, function(x) grepl(x, art$content)))
rownames(mentions) <- art$title

        apple samsung whirlpool
title 1     1       0         0
title 2     0       0         1
title 3     0       1         0
title 4     1       1         0
title 5     0       0         0
```